# Here,Every time i am replacing fragment but Gridview contain items always behind my fragment UI.If there is any logic so i can remove previous view

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.example.nimeshbhalani.webservice.MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="200dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/fragmnt"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Main activity has grid items now I want to replace this fragment
how can I get?grid items is under fragment UI component.

Comment: You need to describe what you really wanna achieve. It's unclear here. Please try to post edit post with understandable intentions. Maybe pictures might help people understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overcome this by adding a background color to root layout of your fragment `android:background="#FFFFFF"`.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```